# GStreamer Model-Proc File Configuration for Human Pose Estimation - OpenVINO

Tags: gstreamer

I'm currently working on creating a GStreamer model-proc file for the OpenVINO model human-pose-estimation-0007. I already have a working example for human-pose-estimation-0001, and you can find the model-proc file.

The human-pose-estimation-0001 model is a multi-person 2D pose estimation network based on the OpenPose approach, utilizing a tuned MobileNet v1 as a feature extractor. It detects up to 18 keypoints, including ears, eyes, nose, neck, shoulders, elbows, wrists, hips, knees, and ankles.(https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.2/omz_models_model_human_pose_estimation_0001.html)

Here's the corresponding model-proc file for human-pose-estimation-0001:

```
{
"json_schema_version": "2.2.0",
"input_preproc": [
    {
        "format": "image",
        "params": {
            "color_space": "BGR",
            "resize": "aspect-ratio",
            "padding": {
                "stride": 8,
                "fill_value": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
            }
        }
    }
],
"output_postproc": [
    {
        "converter": "keypoints_openpose",
        "point_names": [
            "nose", "neck", "shoulder_r", "elbow_r", "wrist_r", "shoulder_l", 
            "elbow_l", "wrist_l", "hip_r", "knee_r", "ankle_r", "hip_l", 
            "knee_l", "ankle_l", "eye_r", "eye_l", "ear_r", "ear_l"
        ],
        "point_connections": [
            "shoulder_l", "shoulder_r", "nose", "eye_l", "nose", "eye_r", 
            "eye_l", "ear_l", "eye_r", "ear_r", "elbow_l", "shoulder_l", 
            "elbow_r", "shoulder_r", "wrist_l", "elbow_l", "wrist_r", 
            "elbow_r", "hip_l", "knee_l", "hip_r", "knee_r", "knee_l", 
            "ankle_l", "knee_r", "ankle_r"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to configure the model-proc file for human-pose-estimation-0007, which is based on the EfficientHRNet approach. The model detects up to 17 keypoints, excluding the neck(https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.2/omz_models_model_human_pose_estimation_0007.html).
I've adjusted the model-proc file as follows which i refer from (https://dlstreamer.github.io/dev_guide/model_proc_file.html):

```
{
"json_schema_version": "2.2.0",
"input_preproc": [
    {
        "format": "image",
        "params": {
            "color_space": "BGR",
            "resize": "aspect-ratio",
            "padding": {
                "stride": 8,
                "fill_value": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
            }
        }
    }
],
"output_postproc": [
    {
        "converter": "keypoints_hrnet",
        "point_names": [
            "nose", "shoulder_r", "elbow_r", "wrist_r", "shoulder_l", 
            "elbow_l", "wrist_l", "hip_r", "knee_r", "ankle_r", "hip_l", 
            "knee_l", "ankle_l", "eye_r", "eye_l", "ear_r", "ear_l"
        ],
        "point_connections": [
            "shoulder_l", "shoulder_r", "nose", "eye_l", "nose", "eye_r", 
            "eye_l", "ear_l", "eye_r", "ear_r", "elbow_l", "shoulder_l", 
            "elbow_r", "shoulder_r", "wrist_l", "elbow_l", "wrist_r", 
            "elbow_r", "hip_l", "knee_l", "hip_r", "knee_r", "knee_l", 
            "ankle_l", "knee_r", "ankle_r"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However i keep encountering this error:

```
    "ERROR default inference_impl.cpp:833:InferenceCompletionCallback: 
Post-processing has been exited with FAIL code."
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!